# Launching the simulation for given step in Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-engine

i am working with simulink model where i have to launch my simulation for a specific time period. currently i am using

```
set_param('model_name','StartTime','0','StopTime','5');  
set_param('model_name','SimulationCommand','start');
```

the problem with this approach is when simulation ends and i start it again, it starts from the beginning and all the simulation progress will lost. here i want to run the simulation from last state.How to do this?

Comment: what are you doing in-between the steps? Are you changing states of you model? Do you have considered to call all functions directly from Simulink?

Comment: i am running it from matlab engine. i run the simulation for specific time period and after it stopped i query some of the workspace variable and repeat the process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save the state of your model to relaunch it again from the last state.
Save the state of your model using this command before starting the simulation

```
set_param('yourModelName','SaveFinalState','on','FinalStateName','myFinalStateVar','SaveCompleteFinalSimState','on')
```

and before launching the simulation again set the initial state of the model by using the command

```
set_param('yourModelName','LoadinitialState','on','InitialState','mySimState')
```

this way you will launch the simulation from exactly last state you left.